# SSRS trying to deploy to wrong server

Tags: ssrs, reporting, visual-studio-2015

I added a report project to my existing solution in VS2015, built some reports and now I am trying to deploy the project to a report server. I have gotten the URL from the config manager ( http://MyServer/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS ) and put that in the report project properties as the target server URL.

When I click Deploy I get an error saying "The specified report server http://localhost/reportserver could ot be found.

I have no idea where it is getting this localhost reportserver URL from, that is not what is saved in the properties. The Report project is inside a solution with an MVC project. Do I need to change something at the Solution level?

Comment: Sounds like you have it set up correctly.  The only other thing I would recommend is go back into the report project properties and click the Configuration Manager button.  Make sure the Configuration is set to the Configuration you modified the Server URL.  You can have multiple configurations set differently, but only one selected for the report.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to run as VS as an administrator.  I guess because of the remote nature of the server.